# MobileFirst sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, ssl-certificate, maximo-anywhere

I'm getting the following error in the Eclipse console when trying to connect my App (IBM Maximo Anywhere):

```
[WARNING ] FWLSE0239W: Authentication failure in realm 'CustomAuthenticationRealm': javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.secur
ity.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target [project MaximoAnywhere]
```

I'm using MobileFirst Studio 7.1 within Eclipse. My backend server has a single, self signed certificate. I have imported the backend server's cert into the following keystores on the machine:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\security\cacerts
C:\Java\jre1.8.0_102\lib\security\cacerts
C:\IBM\Anywhere\MaximoAnywhere\server\conf\default.keystore
```

My MobileFirst Development Server has the following keystore entry in the server.xml file:

```
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="worklight"/>
```

My worklight.properties has the following entries:

```
ssl.keystore.path=conf/default.keystore
ssl.keystore.type=jks
ssl.keystore.password=worklight
```

I have tested keystore connectivity to the backend target using these utilities: SSLPoke and Portecle

Both utilties connect all three of the above mentioned keystores to the backend target server over port 443 with no problems.

I am wondering if anyone has any further comments or suggestions.

Comment: I actually was able to resolve the problem. The cert also needed to be added to the following keystore:

C:\Users\Username\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\resources\security\key.jks

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> I actually was able to resolve the problem. The cert also needed to be added to the following keystore: C:\Users\Username\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\‌​worklight\resources\‌​security\key.jks